# Passing a javascript function to ReactJS.NET Server side

Tags: c#, reactjs.net

I have a pretty basic, but probably complicated question.

I am using ReactJS.net to render react components server side.  I have a typeahead component which I use multiple times throughout my site.  One of the properties it expects is a javascript filter function.

I don't want to have to create a seperate component for each instance of the typeahead, but would like to pass in a javascript function as a property so that I can reuse the component throughout the site.

For example, to render a component on the server I would do the following.  The second parameter is the properties argment

`@Html.React("Components.WorkSiteTypeahead", new { filterFn = model.SomeFunction })`

Now as ReactJS.net expects native c# objects (string, array, list, etc), I don't see any straight forward way to pass in a Javascript function. Any ideas on how would I go about telling my MVC5 view to render my function not as a string? My first instinct is that there might be some sort of Javascript Raw type I am not aware of, but haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Of course after I posted this I figured it out.  Newtonsofts JRAW does the trick `filterFn= new JRaw("function() {doStuff())}")`

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer and mark it as accepted. It's okay to accept your own answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected, at least one way to go about this is to use Newtonsoft's JRAW Type.

```
@Html.React("Components.WorkSiteTypeahead", new { filterFn = JRaw("function(){//do stuff } "})
```